# Microsoft Graph - Memberof fields are null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I've trying to get the groups a user is a member of, in C#. To do so i've been using the /memberOf endpoint, like so:

```cs
public async Task<IUserMemberOfCollectionWithReferencesPage> Test()
{
    var graphClient = GetGraphClient(config);

    return await graphClient
        .Users["user@contoso.com"]
        .MemberOf
        .Request()
        .GetAsync();
}
```

The get graph client function is:

```cs
public static GraphServiceClient GetGraphClient(Config config)
{
    var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
    {

        // get an access token for Graph
        var accessToken = GetAccessToken(config).Result;

        requestMessage
            .Headers
            .Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }));

    return graphClient;
}
```

The problem is that the response is just:

```
[
{
   "deletedDateTime":null,
   "id":"48215c29-5442-4fbe-b6b4-ce3e1b09157a",
   "oDataType":"#microsoft.graph.group",
   "additionalData":{
      "deletedDateTime":null,
      "classification":null,
      "createdDateTime":null,
      "creationOptions":[

      ],
      "description":null,
      "displayName":null,
      "expirationDateTime":null,
      "isAssignableToRole":null,
      "mail":null,
      "mailEnabled":null,
      "mailNickname":null,
      "membershipRule":null,
      "membershipRuleProcessingState":null,
      "onPremisesDomainName":null,
      "onPremisesLastSyncDateTime":null,
      "onPremisesNetBiosName":null,
      "onPremisesSamAccountName":null,
      "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier":null,
      "onPremisesSyncEnabled":null,
      "preferredDataLocation":null,
      "preferredLanguage":null,
      "renewedDateTime":null,
      "resourceBehaviorOptions":[

      ],
      "resourceProvisioningOptions":[

      ],
      "securityEnabled":null,
      "securityIdentifier":null,
      "theme":null,
      "visibility":null
   }
}
]
```

The app has the following permissions:

```
Directory.AccessAsUser.All
User.Read.All
User.ReadWrite.All
UserAuthenticationMethod.Read.All
UserAuthenticationMethod.ReadWrite.All
Directory.Read.All
Directory.ReadWrite.All
Group.Read.All
GroupMember.Read.All
User.Read
```

Every other endpoint im using, the delta, user, subscriptions, work as intended but for unknow reasons they are just null with /memberOf.
I really hope you guys can help, with what im doing wrong, because i've been banging my head against a wall for way too long :).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please try with the graph explorer and check the expected result set

Comment: @SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity Thanks for the comment. With graph explorer i get the expected result, same in postman. I also acquired an access token for the azure ad application and tried that in postman and get the expected result. While some of the fields are null in the expected result, most are filled out. So as far as i can locate the C# SDK seems to be where it fails.

Comment: please try this [sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample) with var result = await graphClient.Users[upn].MemberOf
.Request()
.GetAsync();

Comment: thanks @SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity. Turns out the solution was the GetAllPagesAsType function from the basecontroller. Using that function i get the result. Turns out the problem is one of casting.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation can I move the  comments to answer , so that it may help others

Comment: Of course you may, should probably include the function that fixed it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Get the user MemberOf please use below query in the below sample

```
 var result = await graphClient.Users[upn].MemberOf .Request() .GetAsync();
```

Uses a page iterator to get all directoryObjects

```
protected async Task<List<T>> GetAllPagesAsType<T>(
                GraphServiceClient graphClient,
                ICollectionPage<DirectoryObject> page) where T : class
            {
                var allItems = new List<T>();
    
                var pageIterator = PageIterator<DirectoryObject>.CreatePageIterator(
                    graphClient, page,
                    (item) => {
                        // This code executes for each item in the
                        // collection
                        if (item is T)
                        {
                            // Only add if the item is the requested type
                            allItems.Add(item as T);
                        }
    
                        return true;
                    }
                );
    
                await pageIterator.IterateAsync();
    
                return allItems;
            }
```

Please refer to this sample for [more detail](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample)